# Drawing two TQFT diagrams (a circle and a loop) using xypic

Tags: circles, tqft

I have been searching online the last few hours and how do you draw the following two diagrams using xypic? I used the following but the circle looks too small. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy} 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\xy
\vcap\vcap-
\endxy
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I think the first image could be drawn using this (see below), and the second image below is the best I can do for now:

```
\begin{equation} 
\xy 
(6,0)*{}="1"; 
(-6,0)*{}="2"; 
"1";"2" **\crv{(7,15)&(-7,15)} 
?(0)*\dir{>} ; 
"2";"1" **\crv{ (-7,-15)& (7,-15)} 
?(.05)*\dir{>} ; 
\endxy    
\quad = 1  
\quad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 
\xy 
(-6,-12)*{} ; (-6,12)*{}**\crv{(-6,6)} ?>*\dir{>}; 
{\ar@/_1pc/(-6,1)*{};(-15,1)*{}};
{\ar@/_1pc/(-15,1)*{};(-6,1)*{}} \quad = 0
\endxy 
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already loading `tikz`, you could use it:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
baseline=-3pt,
decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
  }
]
\draw[postaction=decorate] 
  (0,0) circle [radius=13pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
=1\qquad\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-3pt]
\draw[->] 
  (0,-1) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=2] 
  (-1,0) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2]
  (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]